# Remote desktop clients are disconnected and some files are damaged

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop

We have a Windows 2008 r2 server using RDP. This is used as a production server for software developer to build applications.

The users are able to login successfully, but after a few hours the appliction they're using will crash, resulting in files being deleted from the server. The applications that are crashing are VS2010, Titanium Studio, and Excel 2007. The number of users is 4-5.

The client are using Vista or windows 7 to connect to the server.

The only event we can link to this issue is the following:
The Desktop Window Manager has exited with code (0x40010004)
This is really frustrating as we are losing huge amount of files.
Any help?

Comment: What is the application that's crashing? How many users are logging on? What files are deleted? Please update your question with more details.

Comment: Vs2010, Titanium Studio, Excel 2007 Are crashing. The number of users is 4 to 5.